# Насколько полон учебный текст исторической песни "Иван Грозный молится по сыне"?

Tags: литература, история, фольклор, источники

В учебнике литературы для восьмого класса в разделе "Исторические песни" приводится отрывок "[Плача](http://gumfak.ru/otech_html/drevne/istor.shtml)". Он начинается со слов "Эх да собирается наш православный царь" и заканчивается на словах "...Не стало млад царевича».

В сети я смог найти лишь отрывки такого же объема (включая приводимый по ссылке).

Поскольку в тексте повторения встречаются  в зачине, но не в завершении приводимого отрывка, а также поскольку "конфликт" лирического героя с "боярами-князьями" не разрешен, то я склонен считать приводимый отрывок неполным.

Правильно ли моё предположение, и если да, то где можно найти полный текст песни?

Comment: http://gumfak.ru/otech_html/drevne/istor.shtml

Answer (score 1):

У песни нет продолжения, оно и не требуется. Это же песня, а не былина, не баллада. Главное здесь - не решение конфликта, а показ эмоционального состояния героя.

Здесь Грозный характеризуется как любящий отец, который не находит покоя после убийства собственного сына, оплакивает его, гневается на бояр, которые шепчутся за его спиной, злословят по поводу слухов о том, что это он сам убил сына, а теперь плачет. Именно передача особого эмоционального состояния, изображение переживаний героя, раскаяния отличают историческую песню от былины.

Больше здесь ничего и не надо.

Comment: А можно ссылку на источник, по которому приводится текст в хрестоматии?

Comment: Смотря какая хрестоматия. Можно верить Вашей ссылке, там именно песни, а не отрывки. Во всех будет так, попробуйте набрать другие источники. У меня нет хрестоматии исторических песен.